# Would the anode heel effect happen in an un-angled anode?

Tags: radiology, x-rays

If the anode of the x-ray machine had a uniform rectangular shape that was directly facing the cathode (not angled), wouldn't there still be a heel effect? I think that the intensity of the x-ray would be higher towards the center of the anode and would gradually decrease towards the edges, the picture below illustrates why.

[image]

So the mid-point of the anode would be more likely to receive x-ray beams since it lies midpoint, whereas the points that lie at the extremes or more near the edge of the anode would receive less x-ray beams because they will be more likely to get absorbed along the way, is my reasoning valid?